# python matplotlib lineplot gradient colour based on percentage change

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some values (between 3 and 6) that I want to plot in a medium-light grey with a thick line plot (about lw=20). However, when the percentage change between two points is greater than some threshold and positive, I want the colour to progress along a gradient to green. When the percentage change between two points is less than some threshold and negative, I want the colour to progress along a gradient to red. Otherwise, I want the colour to remain the original grey.

I start by defining some random mock data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, np.random.randint(3, 6), 1)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, len(x))
```

And then my idea was to interpolate 100 new datapoints evenly spaced between every two datapoints, then define the colour for each of those datapoints based on condition.

```
R, G, B = 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
red = (1, 0, 0)

all_y = np.array([])
for i, yval in enumerate(y):

    if i == 0:
        continue

    diff = y[i]-y[i-1]
    step = diff/100
    if diff != 0.0:
        y_grain = np.arange(y[i-1], y[i], step)
    else:
        y_grain = np.repeat(y[i], 100)

    all_y = np.append(all_y, y_grain)

    # Set all colours
    r,g,b = R, G, B # temp rgb vals to update according to pct change
    if diff < -1:
        pass # colour progressive red
    elif diff > 1:
        pass # colour progressive green
    else:
        # colour grey
#        clrs = [(r,g,b,1) for j in y_grain]


# Set the colours


all_x = np.arange(0, len(all_y)/100, 0.01)
plt.plot(all_x, all_y, lw=15, c=clrs)
```

One problem is that the clrs array (of RGBA values) does not work for some reason (I thought I did it this way before). Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: `plt.plot` only takes a single color. You will need to use a `LineCollection` (or many `plt.plot`s, but that is slow).

Comment: Yes this is a similar problem, but it really isn't clear to me how to go from the solution in that post to my specific case (hence why I asked a new question). So at least for me this other post does not answer my question and I could use some assistance with that.

Comment: Currently the question does not even contain any effort to use a `LineCollection`, so it's impossible to know where you need help